# need better explanation of services with explicid intents

Tags: android, service, android-intent

there are a few intents i am looking to use and I am pretty sure that they cant be registered in the manifest such as action_screen_off.

so when i start the service:

```
context.startService(new Intent(context, Service.class));
```

then the onCreate registers a broadcast reciever like this:

```
registerReceiver(screenReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON));
```

and my onStartCommant returns start_not_sticky

the receiver should be fired each time the screen goes off correct? but it dosent.
i tried this with a few different receivers like action_battery_changed and they dont work either. how do i get them to fire correctly?

maybe explain to me how it all works a little better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help

http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/